# python: inheritance from class defined in module leads to attribute error

Tags: python, inheritance, module

I can't figure out why my code is not working. I try to create an instance variable in the constructor of my class. This works when the class doesn't inherit from another class as well as when it inherits from a class I defined within the same scope. But when I try to inherit from a class from an imported module, I get an `AttributeError` when I try to create a simple variable. Here is the code:

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
class HeatmapLines(go.FigureWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        self.y_heatmap_lines=4

a=HeatmapLines()
```

And the error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-104-67db37616276> in <module>
----> 1 a=HeatmapLines()

<ipython-input-103-49446a09e448> in __init__(self)
      1 class HeatmapLines(go.FigureWidget):
      2     def __init__(self):
----> 3         self.y_heatmap_lines=4
      4 
      5 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plotly/basedatatypes.py in __setattr__(self, prop, value)
    722         else:
    723             # Raise error on unknown public properties
--> 724             raise AttributeError(prop)
    725 
    726     def __getitem__(self, prop):

AttributeError: y_heatmap_lines
```

All I can find on Google is examples with parent classes defined directly before the child class. Can anyone hint me to what's different here and / or how I can fix this?

Comment: You need to initialize the parent class. e.g. :           Use the super() Function [See https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_inheritance.asp]

Comment: Hey Jim, thanks for your reply. Calling the constructor of the parent class does not fix the issue. And why would it? As Kevin suggested the same, can please anybody explain to me the logic behind this?

Comment: That probably means that your base  lass is not a "normal" python class but maybe something from a c extension or otherwise wrapped compiled code?

Comment: Can you give me a hint what you mean by "normal" python class, so I can do some more research? The class I want to use is part of a very common plotting package named plotly. In the documentation, the object I inherit from is defined as a class object: https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.graph_objects.html#module-plotly.graph_objects

Answer (score 0):

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
class HeatmapLines(go.FigureWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        self.y_heatmap_lines=4
        super(HeatmapLines, self).__init__()

a=HeatmapLines()
```

Comment: Hey Kevin thanks for your answer. But it doesn't seem to fix the issue. As far as I can tell this only calls the base class constructor but this doesn't get rid of the error.